# cassandra - logs to find who did what

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I am new to cassandra and mainly from Devops side as to just install and configure cassandr and provide it for use.

There are cases where the table is getting truncated and I am not sure who is doing it, is there way we can check who has done truncation or changes to cassandra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using DataStax Enterprise, you can use **[Audit Logging](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/sec/secAudit.html)** for that.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will try this and get back soon.

Comment: We have implemented this, thanks for the the answer.